# Skycons class with AngularJs expression doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas

I'm making a weather page using Dark Sky's Api, and am trying to use Skycons. I've added Skycons to be used as a class, and not an id. When I use it like so:

> ```
> <canvas class="fog" width="50" height="50"></canvas
> ```

everything works as it should, but when I try to use it like this, with weatherCtrl.demoIcon = "fog":

> ```
> <canvas class="{{ weatherCtrl.demoIcon }}" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
> ```

it doesnt show the icon. I've tried the following ways:

> ```
> <canvas ng-class="weatherCtrl.demoIcon" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
> <canvas class="ng-class:{{ weatherCtrl.demoIcon }}" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
> ```

Interesting to note that while the icon does not show, the border I've added in CSS to .fog does, it show a blank square.

The skycons JavaScript is: https://github.com/darkskyapp/skycons/blob/master/skycons.js

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to the problem. Using

> $timeout(function () {
>         for (i = list.length; i--;) {
>             var weatherType = list[i],
>                 elements = document.getElementsByClassName(weatherType);
>             for (e = elements.length; e--;) {
>                 icons.set(elements[e], weatherType);
>             }
>         }
>       }, 0);

will initialize the canvases after the expressions are evaluated, and will fix the problem